# React-Native - Wordpress Rest API not returning _embedded key in object

Tags: wordpress, api, react-native, media, wordpress-featured-image

The objective is to display the featured_media key in my api call so I can link image to posts.

When I try and call the wordpress restful v2 api with the following url extension:

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed
```

the `_embed` parameter is supposed to return an extra key in the object `_embedded` which it does if I view the Json in a browser, however when I make the call from react-native It does not display the `_embedded` key in the debugger.

I cannot for the life of me work out how to solve it. My guess is it is either to do with RN not accepting http calls over https or something to do with permissions from the API?

I have three wordpress sites I am interacting with, two of which I do not own and one of which I do. The one I own does show `_embedded` but I have not done any configuration to the API permissions.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I can only suggest for Android: If you are running the emulator localhost (127.0.0.1) will refer to that 10.0.2.2 will refer to your actual localhost.

So in that scenario you would use this: http://10.0.2.2:/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/posts

I also share the code,

```html
export default class Posts extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      posts: []
    }
  }
componentDidMount() {
    let dataURL = "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/posts";
    fetch(dataURL)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          posts: response
        })
      })
  }
render() {
    let posts = this.state.posts.map((post, index) => {
      return
      <View key={index}>
      <Text>Title: {post.title.rendered}</Text>
      </View>
    });
return (
      <View>
        <Text>List Of Posts</Text>
        <Text>{posts}</Text>
      </View>
     )
  }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I am using live WP sites so the calls are to the correct URL address not local ones. My code looks quite similar except that in the actual JSON I am after the _embedded key so I can access the featured_media key and subsequently the source_url for the media.

Comment: @StrangeFuture Did you find the solution to this? I have the exact same issue